# How to set ignore rules for desktop effect in KDE?

Tags: compiz, kde, plasma

I'm switching from Unity/compiz to Kde/Kwin. And there is one awesome feature in the compiz "negative" module that I'd lite to reproduce with Kwin "invert" module:

When I use the keyboard shortcut to invert **all windows**, I want to specify filters to **add exceptions** for windows that I never want to invert, such as my console or IDE, which are already with dark backgrounds.
With compiz I could do that with the `Exclude Windows` field, where you can set exclusion rules based on windows' type, class, or title.

How could I do that with Kwin?

I tried the `Special windows settings` filters, but apparently Desktop effects are not included in the set of things you can override there.